# Is there a way to create objects/ table entries during the extension installation in TYPO3?

Tags: typo3

I want to create objects during the installation of an extension. For example I have the following two simple domain models:

```
class Product extends AbstractEntity
{
   protected $name = '';
   protected $sku = '';
   ...
}

class Location extends AbstractEntity
{
   protected $name = '';
   protected $city = '';
   ...
}
```

and a third domain model like:

```
class Mapper extends AbstractEntity
{
   protected $domainModelName = '';
   protected $domainModelProperty = '';
}
```

Now I want too add entries like this:

```
domain_model_name | domain_model_property
Product           | name
Product           | sku
Location          | city
....
```

during the extension installation or directly after the installation, so that the tx_foxexample_domain_model_mapper table will be filled automatically, is this possible?

I know that I can use a initializeAction, but then the entries will only be generated if I add a plugin and visit the page etc., but I want that the entries/ objects already exists before I use a plugin or add some objects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can store your static data in the file `ext_tables_static+adt.sql` which must be located in the root folder of your extension.

According to the [TYPO3 API](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/singlehtml/), you must should use the following command to export your static data

```
mysqldump --password=[password] [database name] [tablename] --add-drop-table > ./ext_tables_static.sql
```

Also make sure, that the table structure of static tables is present in the `ext_tables.sql` file.

The extension `static_info_tables` makes use of this technique. You can have a look at the extension [here](https://github.com/typo3-ter/static_info_tables) for more details.